# How can I find particular id in sqlite3 database if it is auto-increment?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am inserting some value in sqite3 database and retrieving it and showing in tableView
When I put code as below

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UIButton *btn=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 15, 25, 25)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(editTable:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

}




- (void) editTable:(UIButton *) btn {
NSInteger *indexPath = btn.tag;
NSLog(@"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^%d", indexPath);
[self delete:indexPath]; }
```

but when id is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  so it changes values each time, and don't start from zero, 
so how can I find particular id at particular index?

Comment: It's going to depend on your client library (I am not familiar with the objc or iOS ones), but normally the ID is returned on an INSERT statement.

Comment: Id is auto increases as you insert new data, so it is auto, then it won't start from zero,

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is - the value is irrelevant so long as you actually know what it is.  API calls that execute an `INSERT` statement should return rowids (an auto-increment primary key if there is one, or the internal `_rowid` if there isn't)

Answer (score 0):

If you modify an auto increment table that you load into an UITableView, I assume that you sort the tuples and put them on the data source array object which has the  contents of the table in the right order for the data source delegate.

Being that, you can't correlate the index from the datasource array in memory with the id in the sqlite3 table once you have modified the table. Is that the issue you are describing?

An easy workaround would be getting the id from the tuple and making that id available for the delete method somehow, so it can do the deletion based on that id.